# SELECT @@Identity clarification

Tags: php, sql

I am reviewing some code and I was wondering what this code actually does.

```
$stmt = $dbh->query ( "SELECT @@IDENTITY as lastID" );
$row = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_NUM );
$itemID = $row [0];
$stmt->closeCursor ();
```

Comment: [Microsoft SQL server has this special variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which contains the last identity value that is generated by the statement.

Comment: This is equivalent to `$itemID = $dbh->lastInsertID();`.